# Cloud Build error: (gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[The caller does not have permission]

Tags: google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I've seen a few permutations of this question on SO, but none of the response so far have resolved my issue. I'm attempting to deploy to a gen2, pubsub-triggered function to Cloud Functions using Cloud Build.

There are two service accounts involved: I am *not* using the default Cloud Build service account, but have a separate service account that I set up running the build. I also have a separate service account acting as the runtime account for the function.

Service account 1 (the builder) has the Cloud Build Service Account, Cloud Functions Developer, and Pub/Sub Subscriber roles, as well as the Service Account User role for the runtime service account.

Service account 2 (the runtime) has the Cloud Functions Service Agent role.

If I run `gcloud functions deploy` from the CLI, the function builds fine, but Cloud Build (whether triggered automatically or invoked via the CLI via `gcloud builds submit`) consistently fails with `(gcloud.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Ok], message=[The caller does not have permission]`. There's no other useful information in the build log.

Any idea what permission I'm missing?

Comment: Try to check your permissions in Cloud Build > Settings

Answer (score 0):

Does your runtime Service Account have the pub/sub subscriber role? I would suggest adding it as the Cloud Function itself is the one subscribing/pulling the pub sub messages so it would need that permission.